# Finding items in a string via a pattern with SSJS

Tags: regex, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I need to support multiple language in my XPages application. Most documents store some form of history using the pattern: Author - Verb - Subject - Date e.g. "Michael Myers bought a knife on 25/10/1978".

For my language support I would like to setup a translation mechanism and translate the verb and subject. I think about storing the strings in a properties file.

So I want to store the history as followed in my history field:
Michael Myers #bought# @a knife@ on 25/10/1978.

This field is a multi-value field so the output will be a vector but I covert it to an Array via the $U.toArray() xsnippet function so I can use a reverse on it for display purposes.

I want to display the history via a repeat control. Here is what it looks like:

```
<xp:repeat id="rptHistory" rows="1000" var="obj" indexVar="idx">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var $U = {

  /* 
  /* function that always returns an array for the input value
   */
  toArray : function(input) {
    try {

      if (typeof input === "undefined" || input === null) {
        //return empty array
        return [];  
      }

      if (typeof input === "string") {
        //convert string to array (or empty array)
        return ( input.length > 0 ? [input] : [] );
      }

      if (typeof input === "java.util.Vector") {

        //Normally we would use toArray here, but this returns an Object array.
        //If you try to use that in a doc.replaceItemValue call, it fails.
        //sample code:
        //var v = getComponent("input1").getValue();    //returns a Vector if the component contains multiple values
        //v = $U.toArray(v)   //returns an array of Objects
        //doc.replaceItemValue("someOtherField", v);    //fails

        //the solution I used here is to create a JS array and copy the all the Vector's values
        var a = [];
        var it = input.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext() ) {
          a.push( it.next() );
        }
        return a;
      }

      if (typeof input.toArray !== "undefined") {
        return input.toArray();
      }

      if ( input.constructor === Array ) {
        //return input if it's already an array
        return input;
      } 

      //return input as an array
      return [ input ];

    } catch(e) {
      print("$U.toArray: " + e.toString());
    }
  }
}

var coll = compositeData.log;
if(compositeData.sort == "descending"){
    var result = $U.toArray(coll);
    uidArray = result;
    uidArray.reverse();
    uidReversed = uidArray;
    return uidReversed;
}else{
    return coll;
}


}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:panel tagName="div">
        <small>
            <xp:text escape="true"
                value="#{javascript:obj}" />
        </small>
    </xp:panel>
</xp:repeat>
```

In the computed text control I need to provide the translation.

Does anyone have a guess how to find the strings I am looking for?

I tried to setup a regex but I am not sure how I should do this e.g.

```
<xp:text escape="true">
                                <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:var str = obj;
var regexp = new RegExp("^#.*#$");
return regexp.replace(str, "---")}]]></xp:this.value>
                            </xp:text>
```

Answer (score 0):

I use for now:

```
var str = obj;
var regexp = /\@(.*?)\@/;

var translations = regexp.exec(str);

if (null != translations){
    for (i = 0; i < translations.length; i++) { 
        if(null != regexp.exec(str)){
            trans = regexp.exec(str)[0];
            //verb first
            if (null != trans){
                str = regexp.replace(str, history[trans]);
            }
        }
    }
}
return str;
```

The translation strings are stored in a properties files as followed:

```
@verb_bought@=köpte
@subj_knife@=ett kniv
```

So the stored string Michael Myers @verb_bought@ @subj_knife@ on 25/10/1978 becomes Michael Myers köpte ett kniv on 25/10/1978